# Does Hoard on Steam have achievements?

Tags: steam, achievements, hoard

The [store](http://store.steampowered.com/app/63000/) page description report that

> EASTER UPDATE Collect 48 Eggs to
>   unlock the "Egg Hoarder" Steam
>   Achievement!

but usually games that implement Steam achievements show some of them as icon/title list in the right sidebar. Can someone confirm me that they are really implemented inside the game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does. [This](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1904879) thread in the game's forums shows that the game currently has 116 Steam achievements. No clue why the store page isn't showing them though.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, and I currently have 16 of 116, just in case you would like to know.

They are all fairly standard. "Defeat 250 archers" and "Play 100 multiplayer games" kind of stuff.